# Assigning a Hotkey in Autoit

Tags: autoit, hotkeys

I want to use space bar to "click" a specific button in a window with autoit (without focusing the program?), like a "start" button in a game.

I tried to use ControlClick function but It's doing nothing by the way. I think i'm doing something wrong.

```
HotKeySet( "{space}", "MyFunction")

Func MyFunction()
    ControlClick ( "title", "text", controlID [, button = "left" [, clicks = 1 [, x [, y]]]] )
EndFunc
```

Is it something like that?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a loop with a sleep command and that's it.

Comment: Sure, can you help me to do that?

Comment: Where is the problem? Try using the Autoit Window Info to get the parameters like title, text and so on. You can skip the controlID if not available.

Comment: I don't know about the loop with a sleep command.
I tried something but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Open the very good help file and have a look at the two examples from the function HotKeySet. There you'll find fully working scripts with loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your way doing it is good. You are missing the title and the controlID of the ControlClick function. The 1st and 3rd parameter should be set to the title of the window and the control ID of the control.
To get those use the AutoIt tool that comes with autoit installation.
Set those properly and the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

U can use it like this.

First start AutoIt info program to get desired coordinates ( place where u want to click ), use finder tool to get coorinates of mouse and edit it in a script.

So when u run ur script it will do nothing untill u press Spacebar, then it will run function MyFunction 1 time.

So it move mouse on given position, make pause of half second then left click on desired position $x and $y 1 time and srcipt stop untill u press space again then he make same procedure.

I added exit function so u can turn it off by just press ESC key.

```
HotKeySet( "{SPACE}", "MyFunction")
HotKeySet( "{ESC}", "CloseScript")

Global $x = 519 ; x is first value of mouse position
Global $y = 900 ; y is second value of mouse position

While 1
   sleep(10)
Wend

Func MyFunction()
MouseMove($x, $y, 2)                ; moves the mouse pointer do mouse position with speed 2
Sleep(500)                        ; wait 500 ms half of second ( delay )
MouseClick("left", $x, $y, 1, 2)    ; now click left mouse key on mouse position, 1 click with speed 2
EndFunc

Func CloseScript()
   Exit
EndFunc
```